# Django: how to get size data in a queryset

Tags: python, django, django-models

my room table size data is linked with foreignkey with Master table Size data. i want to get size data instance in room instance. any help, would be much appreciated.

> i want to get size data as like my image_set in this "Room" model, i
>   am not getting anything in size data as a result. any help or suggest
>   would be appreciated.

models.py

```
class Room(models.Model):
    title  = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=80)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1080, blank=True, null=True)
    instruction = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    discount_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)

    size = models.ForeignKey("Size", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    capacity = models.ForeignKey("Capacity", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bed = models.ForeignKey("Bed", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    services = models.ManyToManyField("Services")

    category = models.ManyToManyField("Category")

    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-id"]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("server_room_detail", kwargs={"slug":self.slug})

    def get_size(self, obj):
        for s in Size.objects.all():
            return s

    def get_image_url(self):
        img = self.roomimage_set.first()
        if img:
            return img.image.url
        else:
            return None

    def get_last_image_url(self):
        img = self.roomimage_set.last()
        if img:
            return img.image.url
        else:
            return None


def image_upload_to(instance, filename):
    title = instance.room.title
    slug = slugify(title)
    base_name, file_extension = filename.split(".")
    new_filename = "%s-%s.%s"%(slug, instance.id, filename)
    return "room/%s/%s"%(slug, new_filename)


class RoomImage(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey("Room", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.room.title


class Size(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your issue, are you saying that you want to access the `Size` instance related to your `Room` instance?

Comment: yes,  i want to get size data instance in room instance. have any suggest how to do this? @AustinPhilp

Comment: well, based on your model, you should be able to access them via `room.size` which will return the associated size instance. Is this not the behavior you are getting? I think the question would be benefited with a description of what you are currently trying and what the result is

Comment: ohh, i made a silly mistake in my size model, i just replaced __unicode__  to  __str__

Comment: glad to hear you've got it sorted out, consider answering your own question clarifying what resolved the issue, or simply close it so others know that it no longer requires solving